# Spinner con pasos (valores) de 0.5 en 0.5?

Tags: java, spinner

Necesito valores que vallan de la siguiente manera:

> ```
> 0.5   
> 1  
> 1.5  
> 2  
> 2.5  
> 3  
> Etc
> ```

hice una función pero no se si se pueda hacer de otra manera que demande menos código, aquí mi código:

```
private String GetNumber(int spinner) {
        String result = "0";
        if (spinner == 1) {
            result = "0.5";
        }
        if (spinner == 2) {
            result = "1";
        }
        if (spinner == 3) {
            result = "1.5";
        }
        if (spinner == 4) {
            result = "2";
        }
        if (spinner == 5) {
            result = "2.5";
        }
        if (spinner == 6) {
            result = "3";
        }
        if (spinner == 7) {
            result = "3.5";
        }
        if (spinner == 8) {
            result = "4";
        }
        if (spinner == 9) {
            result = "4.5";
        }
        if (spinner == 10) {
            result = "5";
        }
        if (spinner == 11) {
            result = "5.5";
        }
        if (spinner == 12) {
            result = "6";
        }
        if (spinner == 13) {
            result = "6.5";
        }
        if (spinner == 14) {
            result = "7";
        }
        if (spinner == 15) {
            result = "7.5";
        }
        if (spinner == 16) {
            result = "8";
        }
        if (spinner == 17) {
            result = "8.5";
        }
        if (spinner == 18) {
            result = "9";
        }
        if (spinner == 19) {
            result = "9.5";
        }
        if (spinner == 20) {
            result = "10";
        }

        return result;

    }
```

¿Sería la manera correcta o existe otra mas fácil?

Comment: ¿Quiere llenar el `Spinner` hasta un valor limite o qué pretende lograr?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podría simplificar la función que retorna la mitad del parámetro, pero dentro de esta  se validaría si es entero par `num%2==0` , si es así sería el resultado un entero  . caso contrario la división entre `2.0` es la parte más importante que convertirá el resultado en un `float` de ser necesario.

```
public String GetNumber(int spinner){
    if(spinner%2==0) return String.valueOf(spinner/2);
    else return String.valueOf(spinner/2.0);
}
```

En caso que desee llenar el `Spinner` con elementos de `0.5` en `0.5` iniciando por `0.5` bastaría con agregar en un `for` simple de tipo `double` para que inicie e incremento con dicho valor, la función tendrá como parámetro el valor limite de los elementos.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    List<String> spinnerArray;//Elementos del Spinner
    Spinner mispinner ; // Spinner en el Layout
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Instanciamos el Array
        spinnerArray =  new ArrayList<String>();

        fillSpinnerValues(10);//LLamamos a la función con valor máximo 10
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);
        mispinner= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mispinner);
        mispinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void fillSpinnerValues(int limite){
        for (double  i= 0.5   ; i<= limite ; i+=0.5){
            //Comprobamos si es int el valor .Si es así realizamos el cast a int
            // Para no mostrar 1.0  o 2.0  si desea mostrar así simplemente
            // deja la linea spinnerArray.add(String.valueOf(i));
            if(i==Math.ceil(i)) spinnerArray.add(String.valueOf((int)i));
            else spinnerArray.add(String.valueOf(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, es lo que buscaba.

Answer (score 1):

Lo único que se me ocurre es utilizar un switch:

```
private String GetNumber(int spinner) {
    String result = "0";
    switch(spinner){
    case 1:
        result = "0.5";
        break;
    case 2:
        result = "1"; 
        break;
   //Sigue hasta 20
```

Answer (score 0):

La secuencia devuelve la mitad del numero que se ingresa.

```
    public int calcular(int spinner) {
      var res = spinner/2;
      System.out.println(res);
      return res;
    }

    calcular(1);
    calcular(2);
    calcular(3);
    calcular(4);
    calcular(5);
    calcular(6);
    calcular(7);
    calcular(8);
    calcular(9);
    calcular(10);
```

Comment: No es `JavaScript` la pregunta.

Comment: @Dev.Joel gracias por hacerme notar